# The meaning and usage of "Куда + dative + noun"

Tags: словоупотребление

> **Куда** нам еще однa шляпа, и так уже целый склад.

I just heard my girlfriend say this, and I'm not familiar with this particular usage of "куда". What does this sentence mean? Is it meant as a rhetorical question close in meaning to "... никуда не годится" or "К чему ...?"

Comment: К чему, зачем... What the hell do we need another hat for? We could fill a warehouse with what we already have.

Comment: i believe **куда** here refers to a place which is already occupied hence the objection, so it is rhetorical because the lack of place is perceived as obvious... another unrelated use of **куда** is `куда + adjective in comparative form`  in the sense of *much/a lot more* - *куда сильнее, куда известнее* etc.

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка Now you mention it, how does "куда + comparative" compare with "гораздо + comparative"?

Comment: they're synonymous with куда being less formal, BTW not only with adjectives but with adverbs as well

Comment: **куда** in the sense of **гораздо** is used with both synthetic and analytical comparative form and analytical formed not only with **более** but with **менее** as well, there's also `куда как + adverb` which means `very + adverb` but ironically and is rarely used in speech

Comment: Да, это риторический вопрос. Он означает, что шляпа не нужна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Куда нам эта шляпа? У нас их целый склад.**  - Why take this hat, we don't have room for it.

Add "**куда + pronoun in Dative + Infinitive**" to this row.

> **Куда тебе бегать, ты и ходишь-то с трудом!** - Do you really want to run being unable to walk properly?

And simply

> **Куда там!** - No such luck.

It's pretty colloquial, but quite decent.

But the other version is

> **На кой чёрт тебе эта шляпа?** - Why the hell do you need this hat?

**Кой** is a shorter version of **какой**.

"Чёрт" was (and is) a swearing word, that's why it was omitted, and the expression became

> **На кой мне туда идти?** - Why the hell shall I go there?

And later one swearing word was replaced by other swearing words an euphemisms.

Answer (score 4):

The word **"куда"** is commonly used to clarify a location or direction (*"Куда он это положил?"*, *"Куда мне идти?"*).
In this case, word **"куда"** also has a meaning close to explaining the location/direction.
**"Куда ... еще"** in this context means "where we should go/use/store etc.", but with the connotation of uselessness of some extra action.

For example:

> **Куда нам еще одна шляпа?** - Where should we use/store one more hat (we already have enough hats)
>   **Куда нам еще идти?** - Where else should we go (we are already in right place or just too tired to go anywhere else).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are basically right, "Куда нам ... (nominative)" means that you don't really need something. It can be disputed though, so it's not 100% rhetorical, but by saying that you imply that in your opinion the object you are talking about is useless for you.